# Want to save to zoo format (write.csv) and retrieve also keep to same format (zoo) with date indexing from tseries library of R

Tags: r, zoo

can i **keep** the **same datatype`(zoo)`** and date index when i write.csv and read.csv for the tseries library of R instant of change the datatype to dataframe, actually i want to save to zoo format and retrieve also keep to same format with date indexing. **from `tseries` library of R**

**Rcode**

```
library("tseries")

a = get.hist.quote(instrument="VBIRX", start="2022-01-01",
                         end="2022-03-01", quote="AdjClose",
                         provider="yahoo", compression="m", retclass="zoo")
```

**datatype for a**

```
class(a)
a
```

**(a)data**

```
'zoo'
          Adjusted
2022-01-01 10.38586
2022-02-01 10.32541
```

**when i save in csv format**

```
write.csv(a,"a.csv")
b = read.csv("a.csv")
```

**datatype for b read.csv form file**

```
class(b)
b
```

**(b)data after read.csv from file**

```
'data.frame'
A data.frame: 2 × 2
X   Adjusted
<int>   <dbl>
1   10.38586
2   10.32541
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

csv is not the right format to save this data. You may try saving it in rds file.

```
library(tseries)

a = get.hist.quote(instrument="VBIRX", start="2022-01-01",
                   end="2022-03-01", quote="AdjClose",
                   provider="yahoo", compression="m", retclass="zoo")
a
#          Adjusted
#2022-01-01 10.38586
#2022-02-01 10.32542

class(a)
#[1] "zoo"

saveRDS(a, 'a.rds')

b <- readRDS('a.rds')
b
#           Adjusted
#2022-01-01 10.38586
#2022-02-01 10.32542

class(b)
#[1] "zoo"
```